# Traceback (most recent call last) & TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, icmp, traceback

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import random
import struct
import select
import socket


def chk(data):
    x = sum(x << 8 if i % 2 else x for i, x in enumerate(data)) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    x = (x >> 16) + (x & 0xFFFF)
    x = (x >> 16) + (x & 0xFFFF)
    return struct.pack('<H', ~x & 0xFFFF)


def ping(addr, timeout=1, number=1, data=b''):
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW,  socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
    payload = struct.pack('!HH', random.randrange(0, 65536), number) + data

    conn.connect((addr, 80))
    conn.sendall(b'\x08\0' + chk(b'\x08\0\0\0' + payload) + payload)
    start = time.time()

    while select.select([conn], [], [], max(0, start + timeout - time.time()))[0]:
        data = conn.recv(65536)
        if len(data) < 20 or len(data) < struct.unpack_from('!xxH', data)[0]:
            continue
        if data[20:] == b'\0\0' + chk(b'\0\0\0\0' + payload) + payload:
            return time.time() - start


if __name__ == '__main__':
    target = raw_input("Please enter a IP Adress: ")
    print(ping(target))
```

I have tried to script which works for creating packet and send to    icmp packet. I got the error the result of the script is shown below:

```
# python Pinger.py 
Please enter a IP Adress: 89.1.3.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pinger.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(ping(target))
  File "Pinger.py", line 22, in ping
    conn.sendall(b'\x08\0' + chk(b'\x08\0\0\0' + payload) + payload)
  File "Pinger.py", line 11, in chk
    x = sum(x << 8 if i % 2 else x for i, x in enumerate(data)) & 0xFFFFFFFF
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Can you help m to resolve TypeError and Traceback?

Comment: I'd say that something in `payload` is a string, while the rest of what you sent to `chk` has elements that evaluate to integers, and you're trying to add the bitshifted integers with the strings (that's what `sum` does). Or the first element of what you sent to `sum` could be a string, and it's trying to add that to the default start value of 0. That's probably more likely.

Comment: What is the value of `data` when it fails?

Comment: On Python 2.7 [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) returns `str`. On 3.6 it [returns `bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack)

Comment: Payload was turned to bytes. However, it did not worked. conn.sendall(b'\x80\0' + chk(b'\x80\0\0\0' + b'payload') + b'payload')

Answer (score 0):

checkout this !

```
data = b'\0\0\0\0'

list(enumerate(data))
>>> [(0, '\x00'), (1, '\x00'), (2, '\x00'), (3, '\x00')]
```

you missed here

```
x = sum(x << 8 if i % 2 else x for i, x in enumerate(data)) & 0xFFFFFFFF
        ^ << also raise TypeError     ^ this is str
```

I guess, the reason of `TypeError`, function `sum` may use `+` operator.

Comment: How can I change to x in enumarate(data) to int?                                        x = sum(x << 8 if i % 2 else x for i, x in int(enumerate(data))) & 0xFFFFFFFF   was not corrected.

Comment: 1. casting to int.  `int(x)`
2. using `map`. `enumerate(map(int, data))`. Before that, you sure all of data elements can be casted to int.